# Detecting return from location.href (when redirecting to pdf processing url)

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

IHAC that wants to call an aspx that creates a pdf document. The solution currently is like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#print', function (event) {
    location.href = "Handlers/PrintHierarchy.ashx";
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

I want to add a loader to the page while the processing takes place. Something like this

```
$(document).on('click', '#print', function (event) {
    $("#bottomRight").mask("Processing document...");
    location.href = "Handlers/PrintHierarchy.ashx";
    $("#bottomRight").unmask();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

The problem is that I can't detect when my PrintHierarchy.aspx completes and my loader closes immediately.

Can I postpone closing of the loader to when the File Save dialog opens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to detect the file save dialog opening rather than the aspx finishing.

Try this: http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx

Comment: Thanks +phonicx! This definitely looks like a way to go. If I can get the "print people" to add the cookie I might get there. Thanks again :-)

Comment: No problem, could you mark mine as the correct answer if it works - thanks.

Comment: Done! I completely forgot as you were so quick with the answer that SO wouldn't let me flag it right away :-) Thanks again.